# How to upload app to appstore using 7.3

Tags: ios, swift, app-store, xcode7.3

ERROR ITMS-90725: "SDK Version Issue. This app was built with the iOS '10.3' SDK. All new iOS apps submitted to the App Store must be built with the iOS '11.0' SDK or later, included in Xcode [9.0] or later. Please update Xcode and rebuild your app."

getting this error.  Is there any way to upload app without updating the xcode?

Comment: As the error says, you cannot do this and should update Xcode to 9.0 or later.

Comment: so i have to update my code to swift 4 also?

Comment: Not necessarily, although it's recommended. Xcode 9 supports Swift 3 as well.

Comment: is it possible to archive project without converting

Comment: Since archiving the project requires building it, then the answer is **no** if your code is in Swift 2 or older.

Comment: Additionally : Starting July 2018, all new iOS apps and updates submitted to the App Store must be built with the iOS 11 SDK.
Ref - https://developer.apple.com/ios/submit/

Answer (score 2):

No. You need to get a newer version of Xcode. This may involve in you having to fix your code so it's building correctly on a newer Xcode. There may be hacks to get the iOS 11 SDK into Xcode 7.3 but you're very likely to spend a lot of time with this and still fail.

Comment: is it possible to archive my project in xcode 9 without converting to swift 4?

Comment: @MidhunNarayan - no, we can't do this, the syntax is totally different

Comment: You don't need to convert to Swift 4. Xcode 9 also supports Swift 3.